# Problem with curve modifier on zipper

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to create an animation of a zipper unzipping, and I'm having some problems with the curve modifier. The flat planes on the sides of the zipper are deforming to create a crease in it. The planes are part of the same zip object that has an array modifier applied to it. The blend file is [here](https://drive.google.com/a/deentaylor.com/file/d/0B07YADKKdCjWOVJCQlI2dlliWms/view?usp=sharing). Could someone please explain how to fix this, and maybe even send me an updated file for reference along with the explanation?
[image: Top view of the problem]
[image: Side view]
I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waCN_4q7ens&feature=youtu.be), so if anyone can point out to me where I went wrong, that'd be great. Also,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Creator of the tutorial here)

One of the curve handles of the curve that deforms the plane is pointing the wrong way, causing part of the mesh to be flipped upside down, as shown below by the directional arrows of the curve:

[image]

1. Enter 'Edit mode' for curve (Bezier Curve.001).
2. Select the middle curve point, which is the one that is flipped.
3. Rotate the curve point 180 degrees on the 'x' axis (<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>8</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>)
4. Exit edit mode, and if the error hasn't gone, simply turn the curve modifier on and then off and the mesh should refresh.

Comment: Thanks so much. Great channel, by the way. Found it yesterday when I was trying to make a zipper for a social studies project, and I think you have great content. Keep it up :)

Comment: Oh, and even though you say to rotate it 180 degrees, you actually rotate it 90 degrees in your keys. I knew what you meant, just pointing that out.

Comment: @LukeTaylor Thanks for catching that mistake, updated answer.